# node js and json.s

Tags: json, node.js

I am looking how I can use node.js to decode json.

My Application is very simple.
I will get a Request: PUT with json.
I need to check the json body for some value if that is present send a succuess (200) response.

how can I do in node to valid json.

,

Comment: Did you look up reference? http://nodemanual.org/latest/js_doc/JSON.html

Answer (score 0):

```
var code = 'something you need to check';
try {
    var decoded = JSON.parse(code);
    // valid json
} catch(e) {
    // invalid json
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. In a received HTTP -PUT, how can I extract only the jason body? here in your example it is "code: aleady having json

Comment: Listen for "data" event on request object and store all data that comes there to a buffer. When "end" event comes, check the buffer.

Comment: Alex, Thanks you for the reply. I did not get how to do this, can you please show me with a example..